# change netbeans target folder for tomcat 7.0

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, war

We use a external tomcat installation with netbeans. We have legacy war files inside the tomcat/webapps folder.

Now netbeans drops the war file it generates into the target folder. Is there a way I can tell netbeans to drop the war file into the tomcat webapps folder so that I can also debug that war from netbeans?

We use maven and most of the solutions are ant based.

In short how can I change the target folder of war files to tomcat/webapps in netbeans so that I can also debug the application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can debug your application by just dropping the war file in a non-bundled tomcat container.

What works is this:

[Add](http://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/02/installing-tomcat-7-and-configuring-as-server-in-netbeans/) tomcat to your server's in Netbeans.

Then in your Project Properties go to Run and select the Server added above as your Server.

Then add a break point in your app and debug it.

Enjoy

**UPDATE**

To change the distribution path of the war file you have to edit the xml file {project_folder/nbproject/project.properties}

The property `dist.dir` is the destination of the war file when created.

Changing this property to `dist.dir=c:/mydir/dist` will result in this after building your project:

```
Created dir: c:\mydir\dist
Building jar: c:\mydir\dist\Test.war
do-dist:
dist:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 27 seconds)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was thinking if there is some setting inside netbeans to change the target folder for war file so that I can make the target folder to tomcat/webapps instead of workspace/appname/target

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using maven based project and project.properties file does not exist in the project